# Image Resize Code error

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resize

Hey everyone this is code through which we can resize an image but there is an in 1st and 2nd line and i cannot solve this please help me

```
Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image2);
        /*String incident_ID = IncidentFormActivity.incident_id;*/

        String imagepath = "\1.jpg";
        File file = new File(imagepath);

                double xFactor = 0;
                double width = Double.valueOf(image2.getWidth());
                Log.v("WIDTH", String.valueOf(width));
                double height = Double.valueOf(image2.getHeight());
                Log.v("height", String.valueOf(height));



        Log.v("Nheight", String.valueOf(width*xFactor));
        Log.v("Nweight", String.valueOf(height*xFactor));
        int Nheight = 480;
        int NWidth = (int) ((Nheight * width)/height);

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( image2,NWidth, Nheight, true);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
```

Comment: the error occurs in these lines

Comment: Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); imageView.setImageBitmap(image2);

Comment: Please post the error..

Comment: Look at this API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html this API will help you to create bitmap from various sources

Answer (score 0):

use this Function . it works Perfect for me

```
static public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float bitmapRatio = width / height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

here Max size refer to the pixels till the Image will be redudes

for example if you want to reduce to 640px 
simply Call  `

```
Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
getResizedBitmap(image2 , 640);
```